# Wht is missing in this python django model? What is wrong?

Tags: python, django

**Hello, I got an error when I try to migrate in my django model. It looks like something is missing there, like 'to' but what this 'to' mean?:**

```
class Planificare_concedii(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('planificare concedii')
        verbose_name_plural = _('planificare concedii')

    persoana = models.ForeignKey(
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('persoana')
    )
    magazin = models.ForeignKey(
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('magazinul')
    )
    marca = models.ForeignKey(
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('marca')
    )
    an = models.ForeignKey(
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('anul')
    )
    data_inceput = models.ForeignKey(
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('data inceput')
    )
    data_sfarsit = models.ForeignKey(
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('data sfarsit')
    )
    tip_concediu = models.ForeignKey(
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('tip concediu')
    )
```

**This is the error that I got and I don't know exactly what is missing there or what is wrong...**

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to'
```

Comment: Why every foreignkey field is not pointing to any model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your `ForeignKey`s lack the model to which they point. You thus need to specify a model (through an identifier, or a string) `ToModel` to which it points, for example:

```
persoana = models.ForeignKey(
    ToModel,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
    verbose_name=_('persoana')
)
```

A `ForeignKey` needs to refer to a non-abstract other model. Django will (try) to enforce referential integrity by adding a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, given the database supports that.

In case you want to refer to object in most models, you can use a [**`GenericForeignKey`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey), which means you basically have a `ForeignKey` to the `ContentType`, and a field that contains the primary key. But one usually uses a `GenericForeignKey` scarecely, since then referential integrity can no longer be guaranteed, and sophisticated queries with the Django ORM are harder.